# Multiple CSS animation effects in parallel

Tags: css, css-animations

To terrify the guys at Pixar (with my animation skills), I am attempting to get a walking effect to work using CSS ...

Unfortunately, I am unable to work two different animation effects in parallel, I want the `steps` to rotate at a variable rate to the `walkRight` transition.

Here is my current attempt:

#### CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    right: 0;
    animation-name: walkRight;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-duration: 10s;
} 

.hulk {
  -webkit-animation: steps 10s linear 0s;
}

@keyframes walkRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-400px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes steps {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

Here is an example [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebbh9orr/)

Comment: I'm a bit lost. The character is facing us and so not sure how the steps would produce a *walk* effect.

Comment: Both animations run simultaneously in Chrome and Firefox.  Are you using a browser that doesn't recognize webkit?  Why have you specified one transform as webkit and the other generically?

Comment: @EdwardD I want the `steps` to move faster, independent of the transitionX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to:

- Use `animation-iteration-count: 10` on `hulk` class and set is duration to `1s` (as walkRight has 10s duration), this means the `walk` effect will be applied 10 times during the walk.
- Prefix all properties using `-webkit-` to make sure browsers will render your animation properly, you could use [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) (or similar) which does the job for you automatically.

```css
 .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: walkRight;
      animation-name: walkRight;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
      animation-duration: 10s;
}
.hulk {
  -webkit-animation: steps 1s linear 0s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 10;
      animation-iteration-count: 10;
}
@-webkit-keyframes walkRight {
  0% {
-webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
        transform: translateX(-400px);
  }
  100% {
-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes walkRight {
  0% {
-webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
        transform: translateX(-400px);
  }
  100% {
-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes steps {
  0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  50% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="hulk" width="100px" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/heroup/images/4/4b/Thing_full_body.png/revision/latest?cb=20120117152657">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `animation-iteration-count` on `steps` animation and set shorter `duration`. You just need to match ending time for both `walk` and `steps` that will repeat itself `n` number of times, so in this case its about 9 if duration is 1s.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  right: 0;
  animation-name: walkRight;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}
.hulk {
  -webkit-animation: steps 1s linear 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: 9;
}
@keyframes walkRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-400px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes steps {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="hulk" width="100px" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/heroup/images/4/4b/Thing_full_body.png/revision/latest?cb=20120117152657">
</div>
```